# Where to start with Computer Vision

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, image-recognition

I am a complete newbie when it comes to computer vision.
Keeping in mind that I'm good at C++, can somebody recommend me a good book for computer vision?
The software I design shall be very efficient and fast because I'll need to scan continuously neuron pictures and so virtually create the connections between the neurons.

Comment: Google or something?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at these libraries:

- http://opencv.org/
- http://www.vlfeat.org/
- http://libccv.org/

The OpenCV C++ API looks great, and libccv looks promising (they have a cool HTTP API feature).
Currently my favorite "book" is the OpenCV documentation: http://docs.opencv.org

Greetings!

Answer (score 3):

nice freebie on general cv topics : http://szeliski.org/Book/
(guy there loves to hear himself talking, but still a good read!!)

if you opt for opencv, there's  the Learning Opencv book by Gary Bradsky,
http://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/vision/dipakmj/papers/OReilly%20Learning%20OpenCV.pdf
(nice explanations for almost anything, but quite outdated code examples)

Comment: The link to the Cookbook is dead, alas!

Answer (score 0):

good book [Computer Vision](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013608592X). It's about math foundations of CV.

Comment: Actually that is a terrible book. On the face of it appears to be heavily technical, but then it leaves out huge important chunks.